# Importing macro and function from module

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and try figuring out how source files and modules behaves. I've now encountered a problem.

I have to specify `use` in my `src/main.rs` file to use a macro function properly.

###### src/main.rs

```rust
#[macro_use] mod module1;
use module1::*; // <== This line, `use module1::draw_triangle;` works as well.

fn main() {
    draw_triangle!(20, true);
    draw_triangle!(20); // Should perform like draw_triangle!(20, false);
}
```

###### src/module1.rs

```rust
pub fn draw_triangle(max_width: usize, reversed: bool) {
    if reversed {
        for i in (1..max_width).step_by(2) {
            let repeated = "*".repeat(i);
            let space_length = (max_width - i) / 2;
            let space = " ".repeat(space_length);
            println!("{}{}", space, repeated);
        }
    } else {
        for i in (1..max_width).step_by(2).rev() {
            let repeated = "*".repeat(i);
            let space_length = (max_width - i) / 2;
            let space = " ".repeat(space_length);
            println!("{}{}", space, repeated);
        }
    }
}

macro_rules! draw_triangle {
    ($a: expr, $b: expr) => {
        draw_triangle($a, $b);
    };
    ($a: expr) => {
        draw_triangle($a, false);
    };
}
```

Or, in the macro of modules1.rs, use `module1::draw_triangle`.

It seems that `macro_rules!`, like macro function in C/C++, replaces the expression at build time.

What I want to achieve is to import the module without the `use` statement, while the module will not have to specify the scope of the function. Like this:

```rust
#[macro_use] mod module1;

fn main() {
    draw_triangle!(20, true);
    draw_triangle!(20);
}
```

Stating module name in `macro_rules!` seems not feasible, as we can have "aliases" for modules like https://users.rust-lang.org/t/importing-module-and-aliasing-it-at-the-same-time/72570 mentioned.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I'm using Rust 1.68.0 right now, if this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$crate` within a macro to refer to the crate the macro is defined in, since you control everything in that namespace renaming isn't an issue with that.

```rust
fn main() {
    draw_triangle!(20, true);
    draw_triangle!(20); // Should perform like draw_triangle!(20, false);
}

mod module1 {
    pub fn draw_triangle(max_width: usize, reversed: bool) {
        if reversed {
            for i in (1..max_width).step_by(2) {
                let repeated = "*".repeat(i);
                let space_length = (max_width - i) / 2;
                let space = " ".repeat(space_length);
                println!("{}{}", space, repeated);
            }
        } else {
            for i in (1..max_width).step_by(2).rev() {
                let repeated = "*".repeat(i);
                let space_length = (max_width - i) / 2;
                let space = " ".repeat(space_length);
                println!("{}{}", space, repeated);
            }
        }
    }

    #[macro_export]
    macro_rules! draw_triangle {
        ($a: expr, $b: expr) => {
            $crate::module1::draw_triangle($a, $b);
        };
        ($a: expr) => {
            $crate::module1::draw_triangle($a, false);
        };
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=af1d4ed77ed7b685f0d6fa4540d95baf)

Comment: Wow that's fairly simple! I thought it was `$crate::draw_triangle` for some reason. I've digged out the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#hygiene) about `$crate` after trying your answer. It mentioned that calling function requires full path when using non-macro item. Thank you @cafce25